# Relations issue in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Two models in question are Projects and Events.

Following are the relations:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Project' => array(
        'className' => 'Project',
        'foreignKey' => 'project_id'

    ),

var $hasMany = array(
    'Event' => array(
        'className' => 'Event',
        'foreignKey' => false,
        'dependent' => false,

    ),
```

The problem is that whenever I try to list all of the project, only the ones that have events attached are listed. 
I look forward to having this solved.

Here is the query that I get:

> SELECT `Event`.`id`, `Event`.`project_id`, `Event`.`user_id`, `Event`.`date`, `Event`.`hours`, `Event`.`minutes`, `Event`.`xhours`, `Event`.`xminutes`, `Event`.`xdetails`, `Event`.`assignment`, `Event`.`start_time`, `Project`.`id`, `Project`.`name`, `Project`.`customer_id`, `Project`.`project_nr`, `Project`.`address`, `Project`.`post_nr`, `Project`.`city`, `Project`.`company_id`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`employee_nr`, `User`.`name`, `User`.`surname`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`role`, `User`.`phone`, `User`.`address`, `User`.`post_nr`, `User`.`city`, `User`.`token_hash`, `User`.`company_id` FROM `scheduling`.`events` AS `Event` LEFT JOIN `scheduling`.`projects` AS `Project` ON (`Event`.`project_id` = `Project`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `scheduling`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Event`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) WHERE 1 = 1 LIMIT 15

The Query that I get after the last update is following:

> SELECT `Event`.`id`, `Event`.`project_id`, `Event`.`user_id`, `Event`.`date`, `Event`.`hours`, `Event`.`minutes`, `Event`.`xhours`, `Event`.`xminutes`, `Event`.`xdetails`, `Event`.`assignment`, `Event`.`start_time`, `Event`.`material_id`, `Event`.`km_drive`, `Event`.`time_drive`, `Event`.`finish_time`, `Project`.`id`, `Project`.`name`, `Project`.`customer_id`, `Project`.`project_nr`, `Project`.`address`, `Project`.`post_nr`, `Project`.`city`, `Project`.`company_id`, `Project`.`color`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`employee_nr`, `User`.`name`, `User`.`surname`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`role`, `User`.`phone`, `User`.`address`, `User`.`post_nr`, `User`.`city`, `User`.`token_hash`, `User`.`company_id`, `User`.`car_id` FROM `scheduling`.`events` AS `Event` LEFT JOIN `scheduling`.`projects` AS `Project` ON (`Event`.`project_id` = `Project`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `scheduling`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Event`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) WHERE 1 = 1 LIMIT 20

Here is the array that I get when trying to list Projects:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Event' => array(
        'id' => '57',
        'project_id' => '13',
        'user_id' => '1',
        'date' => '2013-08-07',
        'hours' => '2',
        'minutes' => '35',
        'start_time' => '00:00:00',

    ),
    'Project' => array(
        'id' => '13',
        'name' => 'new project',
        'customer_id' => '2',
        'project_nr' => '215',
        'company_id' => '1',
    ),
    'User' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'id' => '1',
        'employee_nr' => null,
        'role' => 'manager',
        'phone' => '11 12 13 14',
        'token_hash' => null,
        'company_id' => '1',
        'car_id' => null
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'Event' => array(
        'id' => '72',
            'project_id' => '13',
        'user_id' => '1',
        'date' => '2013-08-08',
        'hours' => '5',
        'minutes' => '35',
        'start_time' => '00:00:00',
    ),
    'Project' => array(
                    'id' => '13',
        'name' => 'new project',
        'customer_id' => '2',
        'project_nr' => '215',
        'company_id' => '1',

    ),
    'User' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'id' => '1',
        'employee_nr' => null,
        'role' => 'manager',
        'phone' => '11 12 13 14',
        'token_hash' => null,
        'company_id' => '1',
        'car_id' => null
    )
),
```

So basically I get the list of Events with the related projects and without related Customers. What I want to get is an array like this:

```
(int) 1 => array(
    'Project' => array(
                    'id' => '13',
        'name' => 'old project',
        'customer_id' => '2',
        'project_nr' => '215',
    ),
            'Customer' => array(
        'id' => '2',
            'project_id' => '13',
        'address' => 'abc',
        'initials' => 'HUJ',
    ),
),
```

Comment: please add your query here which you have used to retrive projects

Comment: Please provide you query and tell me these relations are in which model?

Comment: the brlongsTo relation is in Event model, and hasMany is in Project model. 

I have added the query to the question.

Comment: Your question should state 2 things: What are you trying to find? What have you tried? E.g., You are trying to list all the Project and their Events (if any). You have tried $this->Project->find('all') in ProjectsController but it did not work. Your question needs to have mroe details for people to help you.

Comment: please enter your code here not result query

Comment: Try `$this->Project->find('all');` instead of `$this->Event->find('all');`

Comment: I would like to list all of the Projects, no matter if they have Events attached or not.
Here is the code that I use: $this->Project->recursive = 0; $this->set('projects', $this->paginate());

Answer (score 1):

Event Model

```
class Event extends AppModel {
     public $actsAs = array('Containable');

    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Project' => array(
            'className' => 'Project',
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id'
        ),
        // ... more relationships
    );
```

Project Model

```
class Project extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');

    var $hasMany = array(
        'Event' => array(
            'className' => 'Event',
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id'
            'dependent' => false,
        ),
        // ... more relationships
    );
```

Projects Controller

```
class ProjectsController extends AppController {

    public $paginate = array(
        'Project' => array(
            'contain' => array(
                 'Event',
                 'User'
             ) // end Project contain
         ) // end Project pagination
     ); // end pagination

     public function index() {
         $this->set('projects', $this->paginate());
     }
```

Comment: But it still returns only the projects that have events associated with them. What I want is the index() to return all of the projects no matter if they have any events or not.

Comment: see updated foreignKey for the Project hasMany Event relationship.

Comment: Well it lists all of the Projects now, but every projects belongsTo customer, and in the index view, the customer field is empty for every project. Even though in the view function where only one project is listed, the customer is attached to it.

Comment: Please see my edit on how Project contains User in the `$paginate` array. Your model relationships were unclear because in your question when you wrote the resulting SQL query you had `LEFT JOIN scheduling.users AS User ON (Event.user_id = User.id)` this to me indicated a relationship of Event belongsTo User but if you have the relationship of Project belongsTo User then please use my new edit.

Comment: Dear bowlerae, thanks a lot for the help, but right now it gets all of the events in an array, so if I try to list the projects(some of them have many events), the projects are being repeated.
All I want to happen is for an array of Projects with their associations and not an array of events or customers.
To the question I have added the query that I get after the suggested changes.

Comment: "All I want to happen is for an array of Projects with their associations and not an array of events or customers" I'm confused by what you mean. Please update your question and display the array you get AND the array you want.

Comment: Dear bowlerae, I have updated my question with the array that I get and the one that I want to get. Could you please take a look at it?